# Tunnel HTTP traffic from Windows machine to local box

Tags: windows-7, tunnel

I'd like to tunnel/forward all HTTP traffic on a given port on a Windows 7 machine to an arbitrary box (in most cases, a MacOS X machine running a web server on the local network, but occasionally on a remote IP). How might I go about attempting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Trivial Proxy](http://www.xrayapp.com/trivialproxy/) to accomplish similar things before.  Rather simple to use and set up.

Using this program, set your local port to 80, your remote port to 80, and remote host to the IP of your Mac OSX machine.

Comment: Just tried TrivialProxy , really simple bloody good program.